# Executar código fortran que solicita leitura de dados no jupyter-notebook com python restart kernel

Tags: python, fortran, ipython-notebook

Jupyter notebook restart quando se roda um código fortran que solicita a entrada de dados, como se segue:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

repare que a variável `a` deve ser fornecida logo após a chamada de `f1` .Entretanto, ocorre um erro e o kernel restart :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação: O código funciona bem sem o trecho de declaração de `a` e leitura de `a`

Answer (score 1):

O problema acontece devido ao notebook jupyter não conseguir processar a entrada padrão (*stdin*) em sub-processos.

Mesmo que você execute um comando *shell* (executado, também, em um sub-processo) que utilize a entrada padrão, o kernel irá "travar" (eventualmente emintindo uma mensagem de *restart* ou não).

Exemplo, se você executar o comando abaixo em uma célula do notebook:

em Windows:

```
!set /p variavel="Digite um valor "
```

ou UNIX / OS X:

```
!read -p "Digite um valor " variavel
```

o kernel "trava", esperando a entrada.

---

Uma solução possível para esse problema: ler os valores de entrada no código Python e enviar esses valores como parâmetros para a rotina em Fortran:

```
x=input("Valor X ")
y=input("Valor Y ")
a=input("Valor A ")
f1(x, y, a)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]